# Padding/Margin difference between firefox and safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I am developing a website for a client.

There is a space showing between the LayerSlider and the Header on Firefox, where in Safari I do not have this extra space.

I have done `* {padding:0;margin:0;}` and I have FireBug installed, how can I find out what it causing this space in Firefox?

EDIT: I forgot to include URL to problem, DERP.... http://streamwire.gs-dev.net

Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: Post your code on here for us to look at....

Comment: Or you can [check this] (http://forbrains.co.uk/browser_differences/width_padding_margin_differences)

Comment: Hi Sorry,  just posted the url... cant just paste the code..

Comment: I have don't face this issue. both browser same view in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Firefox, Safari, Chrome all next to each other screenshotted... Firefox has this white gap...

http://i.imgur.com/RI8qcbc.png